# upload more than 1 image with ajax

Tags: php, ajax

I wrote script that alows users to submit comment text with image, and I did it with ajax.

yes - upload image with ajax.

I would like to expand this scrpit and alow users to upload more than one file/image. my code don't support that (server side gets only 1 file). can you help me to fix it so I could upload array of files?

HTML:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" action='#' method="post"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type='hidden' name='comment[pageName]' value='yard' class="pagename-field" />
    <input type='hidden' name='comment[refID]' value='0' class="refid-field" />
    <input type='hidden' name='allowReply' value='1' class="allowReply-field" />

    <textarea class="form-control comment-field" name="comment[text]" rows="1" placeholder="כתוב/י תגובה"></textarea>
    <input type='file' name='file[]' class='form-control file-field hideBox' maxlength='1' accept="image/jpg,image/png,image/jpeg,image/gif"  id="uploadFile0"/>

    <button class="btn btn-primary submit" >SUBMIT</button>
    <img src="images/loading.gif" align="absmiddle" class="loader" id="loader">
</form>
```

JS:

```
$(function() {
    $(document).on('submit','form',function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); 

        var $form = $(this);
        var act = 'add';
        var file_data = $form.find('.file-field').prop('files')[0];   
        var form_data = new FormData();       
        form_data.append('act', act);
        form_data.append('comment[text]',  $form.find('.comment-field').val());   
        form_data.append('comment[pageName]',  $form.find('.pagename-field').val());   
        form_data.append('comment[refID]',  $form.find('.refid-field').val());            
        form_data.append('allowReply',  $form.find('.allowReply-field').val());            
        form_data.append('feel',  $form.find('.feel-field').val());            
        form_data.append('file[]', file_data);
        $("#loader").show();
    //  alert(form_data);

        $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: "ajax/addComment.php",

               dataType: 'text',  
               cache: false,
               contentType: false,
               processData: false,  
               async: false,
               data: form_data,
               success: function(data)
               {
                    $("#loader").hide();
                    $('#commentsBox'+$form.find('.refid-field').val()).prepend(data);
                     $("form").reset(); 
               }

             });

        return false; // avoid to execute the actual submit of the form.
    });
});
```

Comment: Checkout: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=53b9Zop50R8 and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MxMWEYJMcmk and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hqSlVvKvvjQ want more checkout https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCpOIUW62tnJTtpWFABxWZ8g

Comment: Why don't you try: http://dropzonejs.com

Comment: @user1012181 - it seens like  dropzonejs upload the files before i submit the form. thats not good for me...

Comment: Check the documentation. There's option to prevent auto upload.